# Ivy or something else? Want to know the accurate name

Tags: herbicide, poison-ivy, thorns

Please see the pictures. It grows every year in my back yard. I dragged it out but it just comes back. It pricks skin. I don't know the English Name so I don't know how to get rid of it by DIY.

No fruit by the way!

I don't want to use Round up since I heard that it causes cancer.
[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

Comment: If it is a blackberry, don't waste your money on roundup. It doesn't kill it, unless you do several applications. To get rid of it, don't "pull it out," dig the roots up completely..

Comment: @alephzero, is it catbrier?

Comment: We don't have catbrier in the UK, but from the descriptions on the web, it isn't. The leaves are completely different. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smilax for example.

Comment: BTW your pictures are a very young plant. This is what the stems look like when the *seriously* "prick skin:"  https://www.naturespic.com/i/27234PW00_w.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like blackberry, invasive in zone 8 and probably many other zones. I find the fruit to be flavorless but many people love it, birds also love the fruit.

Comment: But it has not any fruit.

Comment: It won't have any fruit if you cut it down to the ground every year. The flowers and fruit grow on the previous year's stems.

Comment: It may also black raspberry rather than blackberry. At least that's what I discovered when examining the fruit on the bushes around my yard.

Comment: There are many different wild varieties of bramble, the plant whose fruit is the blackberry, with differences of flavour. blacksmith37 seems to have been unlucky with theirs; but others are truly delicious. In Britain where the plant is a common native, many people brave the thorns in late summer to collect and eat the fresh wild fruit.

Comment: Black raspberry looks a bit different; my very favorite  berry.